# Conversion from std::pair<T, U> to std::pair<T, V> doesn't work even if V(U) works?

Tags: c++, c++11, std-pair

Here's an example that works on C++03 (-std=c++03) but fails on GCC and VS2015 for C++11 (-std=c++11, /Qstd=c++11)

```
#include <utility>

class B {
public:
   B(float);
};

class A {
public:
   A(B);
};

std::pair<int, A> a(std::make_pair(1, 2.0));
```

I have no idea why this would be invalid.. as far as I can see, the `A` members are direct-initialized by `float` as described in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair . Is there an SFINAE test for implicit convertibility? As far as I can see, on cppreference it doesn't mention anything like that.

Comment: I'm confused, why are you expecting the compiler should go through two conversions without a cast?

Comment: @Mehrdad if `pair::pair(po):f(po.f), s(po.s)`, then there are no two conversions.

Comment: I don't get it, isn't `2.0` a `double`? It needs to be converted to `float`, which needs to be converted to `B` before that can be converted to `A`. That seems to require at least 2 conversions if not 3...

Comment: @Mehrdad there were an answer. but to answer your comment, every user defined conversion sequence supports an additional standard conversion like double to float before the user defined conversion, so that would be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

N3337 20.3

Constructor

```
template<class U, class V> pair(const pair<U, V>& p);

Requires: is_constructible<first_type, const U&>::value is true and
is_constructible<sec- ond_type, const V&>::value is true.
```

Here is call to this constructor, since `make_pair` will return `pair<int, double>`, actually there is another precondition:

> This constructor shall not participate in overload resolution unless
>   const U& is implicitly convertible to first_type and const V& is
>   implicitly convertible to second_type.

So, gcc/clang/msvc are right, this code should not compiled, since `double` is not implicitly-convertible to `A`.

Comment: `is_constructible` seems to be defined as a test of whether "T obj(std::declval<Args>()...);" is well-formed. `A a(2.0)` is well-formed, so should is_constructible not be true and the conversion succeed?

Comment: The other precidition is spot-on. Thanks!